# Add multipart encoding flag to WordPress metabox only when needed

Tags: wordpress

Apparently I have to call the following `add_action` trigger to modify a custom post type metabox form to allow for multipart handling:

`add_action('post_edit_form_tag', [__CLASS__,'form_multipart_encoding'])`

But in this `add_action` logic of my plugin, I don't have access to $post, `get_the_ID()`, etc. How is it possible to only fire this action when in admin screen viewing my certain CPT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post_edit_form_tag` includes the current post object as an argument. You can do something like this to restrict your custom enctype to a specific post type:function

```
post_edit_form_tag($post) {
    if($post->post_type === 'your_custom_post_type'){
        echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
    }
}
```

That will make your enctype only appear for the specific post type you want it on. And is the correct "pattern" for wordpress plugins. You can always see what arguments a hook passes by looking it up on [developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_edit_form_tag/).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the action 'post_edit_form_tag' will affect default Post and Custom Posts. According to WP documentation: Applies to the  tag for the default post edit page (Which is used for pages and custom post types). It is at the end of the form start tag and before the closing bracket.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_edit_form_tag

See custom-meta-box-wpshed to set up a custom metabox properly.
https://github.com/istefan/custom-meta-box-wpshed/blob/master/custom-meta-box-wpshed.php

```html
add_action( 'post_edit_form_tag' , 'post_edit_form_tag' );

function post_edit_form_tag( ) {
        echo ' enctype="multipart/form-data"';
}

/**
  * Save the Meta box values
  */
function wpshed_meta_box_save( $post_id ) {

   // Stop the script when doing autosave
   if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
   // Verify the nonce. If insn't there, stop the script

   if( !isset( $_POST['wpshed_meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['wpshed_meta_box_nonce'], 'my_wpshed_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

   // Stop the script if the user does not have edit permissions
   if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', get_the_id() ) ) return;
   // Save the textfield
     
   // Make sure the file array isn't empty and process the FILE
   if(!empty($_FILES['wpshed_file']['name'])) {
   }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'wpshed_meta_box_save' );
```